# Wordpress REST API not working - local instance, official docker image

Tags: wordpress, docker, wordpress-rest-api

I'm running a local Wordpress instance in a docker container build using wordpress latest image.  According to Wordpress Site Health tool the REST API is not working. I get this error:

```
Error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused (http_request_failed)
```

My docker-compose looks like this

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

I tried also Bitnami image, but the effect is the same.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend solved this for me.

1. Stop the containers.
2. Change `"8000:80"` in `docker-compose.yml` to `"80:80"`.
3. Remove db volume - this will remove all db data

- `docker volume ls` find volume name
- `docker volume rm <name>` in this case it's `wordpress_db_data`

4. Start the containers and go to http://localhost/

You could probably also just update the settings in the Wordpress dashboard but installing it again seemed more convenient.

Now Wordpress Site Health should show no errors.

Comment: Thank you. This also solved "Your site could not complete a loopback request" critical issue.